# how to edit the panel in kendoUI panelbar

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui

I am using kendoUI panel bar.
I have three panels in the panelbar.
I have defined the panel bar as shown below.
I want to edit the panel name in the panel bar.

```
$("#panelBar").kendoPanelBar({
                        expandMode: "single",
                        select: onSelect,
                        dataValueField: "id",
                        dataTextField: "Text",
                        dataSource: 
                            [{
                            text: "First",value:"1", expand: true, encoded: false,
                            content: "<div id='1'></div>"
                             },
                             {
                                 text: "second",value:"2", expand: true, encoded: false,
                               content: "<div id='2'> </div>"
                             },
                             {
                                 text: "Third",value:"3", expand: true, encoded: false,
                                 content: "<div id='3'>  </div>"
                             }
                           ]
                        });
```

Comment: do u want to get the ids-of-panelbar-items?

Comment: no,I want to edit the panels name when i click on the panel